# printing date and time java

Tags: java, date, time

I have a CSV file which contains the following data:

```
red, 03/11/2014, 11:00, 10
blue, 04/11/2014, 12:00, 15
pink, 03/11/2014, 15:00, 50
blue, 05/11/2014, 14:00, 15
pink, 02/11/2013, 12:00, 10
green, 03/12/2014, 23:00, 1
red, 03/11/2013, 23:11, 11
```

I am trying to print the date and the time but keeps failing.
The code works fine when

```
public static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT_DATA = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm";
```

is changed to

```
public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "dd/MM/yyyy";
```

but that will only print the date.

The code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RangeCalculator {
private File file;
public static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT_DATA = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm";

public class Entry {
    String colour;
    String date;
    String time;
    String noise;

    public Entry(String colour, String date, String time, String noise) {
        super();
        this.colour = colour;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
        this.noise = noise;
    }

    // implement getters and setters here if necessary

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Entry [colour=" + colour + ", date=" + date + ", time="
                + time + ", noise=" + noise + "]";
    }
}

public RangeCalculator(String fileName) {
    file = new File(fileName);
}

private List<Entry> computeRange(String from, String to)
        throws FileNotFoundException, ParseException {

    List<Entry> result = new LinkedList<>();

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT_DATA);
    Date fromDate = formatter.parse(from);
    Date toDate = formatter.parse(to);

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    scanner.useDelimiter("[,\n]");

    // maybe you want/need to skip the first line of the file
    // if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    //     scanner.nextLine();
    // }

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {         
        String color = scanner.next();
        String date = scanner.next().substring(1);
        String time = scanner.next().substring(1);
        String noise = scanner.next().substring(1);

        Date currDate = formatter.parse(date);
        if (!currDate.before(fromDate) && !currDate.after(toDate)) {
            result.add(new Entry(color, date, time, noise));
        }
    }

    scanner.close();
    return result;
}

private void printEntries(List<Entry> entries) {
    for (Entry entry : entries) {
        System.out.println(entry.toString());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    RangeCalculator app = new RangeCalculator("Data.csv");

    List<Entry> calculatedEntries = null;
    try {
        calculatedEntries = app.computeRange("03/11/2014 11:00", "04/11/2014 12:00");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: File not found!");
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: Wrong date format!");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    app.printEntries(calculatedEntries);
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: What you exactly want to do if u will take this format dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm then it will parse date and time both

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to parse date only using formatter that includes date and time.
All you need to do is replace this line:

```
Date currDate = formatter.parse(date);
```

with this:

```
Date currDate = formatter.parse(date + " " + time);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are getting Date and time component as two separate field you need to append them both before using. Hence below shall be

Date currDate = formatter.parse(date+" "+time);